# Storing and retrieving photo from database

Tags: php, mysql, html, database, photo

I'm looking to store a photo and retrieve it from the database, but I'm having trouble. I looked through other posts, but couldn't find a solution. The photos are being uploaded to the database, but i can't seem to pull them back out. Also, in the url, $id=0 
but even when I change the $id to equal a corresponding database number, it still just loads a blank page... I know this is a lot of code, so any response would be greatly appreciated!!

CHOOSE_PHOTO.PHP

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="process_photo.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
Choose a file to upload: <input name="image" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

PROCESS_PHOTO.PHP

```
 MY_LOGIN_INFO_AND_DATABASE_CONNECTION

if ($_FILES) {
  $image_types = array 
    ("image/bmp",
    "image/jpeg",
    "image/pjpeg",
    "image/gif",
    "image/x-png"); 
 if (is_uploaded_file ($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"])) {
   $image  = addslashes (fread 
      (fopen ($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "r"), 
      filesize ($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"])));
$file_name = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
$file_size = $_FILES["image"]["size"];
$file_type = $_FILES["image"]["type"];
if (in_array (strtolower ($file_type), $image_types)) {
  $sql = "INSERT INTO image_table "
     . "(image_type, image, image_size, image_name, image_date) ";
  sql.= "VALUES (";

  $sql.= "'{$file_type}', '{$image}', '{$file_size}', "
     . "'{$file_name}', NOW())";
  @mysql_query ($sql, $conn);

exit();
  }
 } 
} 


$id = mysql_insert_id($conn);

mysql_close($conn);

header("Location: photo_preview.php?id=$id");
```

PHOTO_PREVIEW.PHP

```
 MY_LOGIN_INFO_AND_DATABASE_CONNECTION

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM image_table WHERE image_id=  " 
. mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["id"]), $conn);

if(!$result) die(mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($result);


  if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
   {
    $row = @mysql_fetch_assoc ($result);
    $image_type = $row["image_type"];
    $image = $row["image"];
    Header ("Content-type: $image_type");
    print $image;
   } 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your assuming everything is going to work - but it's not working. Take the opposite approach and assume everything is going to fail - as it invariably will. Once you've written it, copy and paste for your next project. Then, when something unexpected happens, you have code there to tell you exactly what.

Several problems:

1. You don't correctly "escape" the entry into the database. You might make it work with "add_slashes" but you should use mysql_real_escape_string() to make all your sting inputs safe. Better still, use prepared statements with `PDO` or `mysqli_()` functions as the `mysql_()` functions are to be depreciated. Useing the prepared statements will automatically escape the strings and make them safe.
2. You hide all errors with your sql inset - '@mysql_query()', and don't check for if it worked or not. you wan `if (!mysql_query()) {' then show errors (use 'mysql_error()`). This is probably where you are going wrong - the input is failing and you are not checking why.
3. You also don't check your 'fread' and 'fopen' etc. work. They could have errors. Use 'file_get_contents()' and check the return value - it's neater. If it returns false then it failed - show errors to work out why.
4. You don't actually check that the file uploaded correctly. check $_FILES["image"]["error"] for something greater than zero.
5. With the `SELECT` you assume the row has been found - but if it isn't (e.g. someone gives you a dodgy id) then $row will be false (and you've get other errors). So check $row is an array and not false before continuing.
6. No error message if the image type doesn't match (the `in_array`). You plough on, use a non-existent ID and redirect to page that is bound to fail (see point 5).
7. You actually have the "exit" before the redirect. Is that expected? You basically say "if I have a working, valid file, stop, but if I don't have a valid file, redirect to the file that doesn't exist...

So - lots to fix. Don't hide errors, but give yourself some feedback when there are errors.